# How to make PDF characters darker for print without using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I am a researcher and I have to read research papers. Unfortunately, the characters are not dark enough, so the papers are hard to read when printed on the paper. Note that the printer's cartridge has no problem, but the characters are not printed dark enough (the text is already in black: take a look at a sample).

This is how the characters look like in Photoshop:

[[image: enter image description here]]

Note that the background is transparent when you import a PDF document in photoshop.

I use this awful solution:

First, I Import the PDF document into Photoshop. The pages are imported as **individual** images with transparent background.

Then, **for each page** I do either of these two methods:

1. Method 1: Copy the layer over itself multiple times, so that the image gets darker
2. Method 2: Apply a **Min** filter on the image

This is how it looks like after conversion (left: Min filter, right: layer duplication)

[[image: This is how it looks like after conversion (left: Min filter, right: layer duplication)]]

Since the images are split by photoshop, I have to open the "print" dialog for each single page and confirm the dialog to have the page printed.

This solves my problem for printing a single page and I can read the printed contents easily. However, **it is hard to convert every page of every PDF paper using PHOTOSHOP, and the print EACH single page separately!!!!**. Is there any wiser solution/tool/application ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Extract all individual pages

Step 2: Set up an [Action](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) to do your above process + saving

Step 3: Create a [Droplet](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) to run that action on each page

Step 4: Combine all files back into a single PDF

Step 5: Print